# reallocating space on matrix of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE* file;
    char ***myTable;
    /* I want to declare a matrix which will contain a string in each cell */
    int end = 1;
    int row = 0;

    /* space declaration */

    myTable = (char ***) malloc(sizeof(char**));   

    myTable[0] = (char **)malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        myTable[0][j] = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while(end) {
        //filling the matrix from the file no matter how many row
        //the file has
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%s", myTable[row][j]);
        }
        //adding one row every time i retrive the data

        myTable = (char***) realloc(myTable, sizeof(**myTable) * (row+1));
        row++;
        if(getc(file) == EOF) end = 0;
    }

    fclose(file);

    for(int rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            printf("numero: %s ", myTable[rows][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create a matrix of strings which will increase the row size every time there is a new line in the file input. The file will look like this.

```
3333333333 date1 u
2222222222 date2 e
```

In this scenario the matrix inside the program will have 2 rows and 3 columns.

In this file

```
3333333333 date1 u
2222222222 date2 e
8888888888 date3 e
```

In this scenario the matrix inside the program will have 3 rows and still 3 columns; the column will always be fixed but the number of row must increase by one each time.

Comment: `myTable = (char***) realloc(myTable, sizeof(**myTable) * (row+1));` should be `myTable = realloc(myTable, sizeof *myTable * (row+2));`?

Comment: stil doesn't work, segmentation fault 11 as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for each new line.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE* file;
    char ***myTable = NULL;
    /* I want to declare a matrix which will contain a string in each cell */
    int end = 1;
    int row = 0;

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while(end) {
        // TODO: Add NULL ptr check....
        // Allocate space here:
        // First, add a row
        myTable = realloc(myTable, sizeof(char**) * (row + 1));
        // Next, alloc 3 pointers in the new row
        myTable[row] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
        // Then, alloc space for 3 strings
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            myTable[row][j] = malloc(MAX_STRING_LENGTH * sizeof(char));

        //filling the matrix from the file no matter how many row
        //the file has
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%s", myTable[row][j]);
        }
        row++;
        if(getc(file) == EOF) end = 0;
    }

    fclose(file);

    for(int rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            printf("numero: %s ", myTable[rows][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: You could simplify things by creating a struct to hold the data:

```
struct my_data {
    char id[100];
    char name[100];
    char data[100];
};
```

Then it simplifies to:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE* file;
    struct my_data * myTable = NULL;
    /* I want to declare a matrix which will contain a string in each cell */
    int end = 1;
    int row = 0;

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while(end) {
        // TODO: Add NULL ptr check....

        myTable = realloc(myTable, sizeof(struct my_data) * (row + 1));

        //filling the matrix from the file no matter how many row
        //the file has
        fscanf(file, "%s %s %s", myTable[row].id, myTable[row].name, myTable[row].data);
        // TODO: check the return value from fscanf

        row++;
        if(getc(file) == EOF) end = 0;
    }

    fclose(file);

    for(int rows = 0; rows < row; rows++) {
        printf("numero: %s %s %s\n", myTable[rows].id, myTable[rows].name, myTable[rows].data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it really simplified the job i was look for

Comment: @MarcoA7 You're welcome. Note I forgot one of the parameters to `realloc`. I've just edited and fixed that.